# Mongodb comparing object arrays keys

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the following sample document saved in my mongodb collection :

```
   {
       _id:"3213dsadsa812321",
       files: [ 
       {_id: "99300", path:"C:\Filename01.txt"},
       {_id: "99301", path:"C:\Filename02.txt"},
       {_id: "99302", path:"C:\Filename03.txt"},
       {_id: "99303", path:"C:\Filename04.txt"},
       ]
   }
```

and I have the following array var dynFiles:

```
  [          
       {_id: "1", path:"C:\folder\textfile01.txt"},
       {_id: "2", path:"C:\folder\textfile02.txt"},
       {_id: "3", path:"C:\folder\textfile03.txt"},
       {_id: "4", path:"C:\Filename04.txt"},
  ]
```

is it possible to find if any of the mongodb document objects array path key match any of the dynFiles var path key?

In other words, based on the given above record _id: "99303" in db should be returned as it match the var object array _id: "4".

Expected result:

```
[ {_id: "99303", path:"C:\Filename04.txt"} ]
```

After extensive research I wrote the following query but unfortunately it doesn't help much as it compare the document files.path keys with a specific object array key, while I need it to compare files.path with all paths of dynFiles. Thanks in advance for your help and time

```
{ 'files.path': {$eq: dynFiles.path} }
```

Answer (score 0):

You would require another array that contains just the mapped paths and this can be derived using JavaScript's **[`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** method. This array will then be used in the mongo query as the **[`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/query/in/)** operator value. The following demonstrates this:

```
var dynFiles = [          
       {_id: "1", path:"C:\folder\textfile01.txt"},
       {_id: "2", path:"C:\folder\textfile02.txt"},
       {_id: "3", path:"C:\folder\textfile03.txt"},
       {_id: "4", path:"C:\Filename04.txt"},
    ],
    paths = dynFiles.map(function(f){ return f.path; });

db.collection.find({"files.path": {"$in": paths }})
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the [`.aggregate()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#db.collection.aggregate) method.

First you need to return an array of "path" using the [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method.

```js
> var dynFiles = [          
...        {_id: "1", path:"C:\folder\textfile01.txt"},
...        {_id: "2", path:"C:\folder\textfile02.txt"},
...        {_id: "3", path:"C:\folder\textfile03.txt"},
...        {_id: "4", path:"C:\Filename04.txt"},
...   ];
> var paths = dynFiles.map(function(element) {
... return element.path;
... });
> paths
[
        "C:\folder\textfile01.txt",
        "C:\folder\textfile02.txt",
        "C:\folder\textfile03.txt",
        "C:Filename04.txt"
]
```

Then comes the aggregation query:

You only need one stage in your pipeline which is the [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project) stage where you use the [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/map/#exp._S_map) operator to return an array of sub-documents that where "path" is in "dynFiles". To check if a given "path" is in "dynFiles" you use the [`$setIsSubset`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/setIsSubset/#exp._S_setIsSubset) operator in [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/#exp._S_cond) expression. The reason you need the `$setIsSubset` is because you can't use the `$in` operator in `$cond` expression. Of course the `$setIsSubset` operator takes two arrays as parameter you need to use the `$map` operator to return one element array. Of course the [`$literal`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/literal/#exp._S_literal) operator let you assign a literal array to the "input" in `$map`. Also you need to use the [`$setDifference`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/#exp._S_setDifference) here to filter out all `false` from the array which is fine as long as the data being filtered is "unique".

```js
db.paths.aggregate([
    { "$project": { 
        "files": { 
            "$setDifference": [
                { "$map": { 
                    "input": "$files", 
                    "as": "file", 
                    "in": { 
                        "$cond": [ 
                            { "$setIsSubset": [ 
                                { "$map": {
                                    "input": { "$literal": [ "A" ] },
                                    "as": "el", 
                                    "in": "$$file.path"
                                }}, 
                                paths
                            ] },
                            "$$file",
                            false 
                        ]
                    }
                }}, 
                [false]
            ]
        }
    }}
])
```

---

Another way and probably the easiest way is by using the [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/#exp._S_filter) operator new in MongoDB 3.2

```js
db.paths.aggregate([
    { "$project": { 
        "files": {
            "$filter": { 
                "input": "$files", 
                "as": "file",  
                "cond": {
                    "$setIsSubset": [
                        { "$map": {
                            "input": { "$literal": [ "A" ] }, 
                            "as": "el", 
                            "in": "$$file.path"
                        }}, 
                        paths 
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }}
])
```

Both queries yield the same result:

```js
{
        "_id" : "3213dsadsa812321",
        "files" : [
                {
                        "_id" : "99303",
                        "path" : "C:Filename04.txt"
                }
        ]
}
```